# React route, use the same component with different props/parameters on CoreUI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, core-ui

Let's say I have a React component called `Component1`, where it makes plots based on the data provided --

```js
import data_A from "./some/folder/A";
import data_B from "./some/folder/B";
.
.
.
import data_Z from "./some/folder/Z";

const Component1 = (props) => {
    var data = /* decide which data to load using props, will come from a nav link click event */
    return(/* render component with data */);
}
```

I have another file where I specify all the routes to the components:

```js
const Component1 = React.lazy(() => import("./views/components/Component1"));

routes = [
    { path: "/components", name: "Component1", component: Component1, }
    // there are more components but they are not relevant here.
];
```

and I build the `<Switch/>` like this:

```js
<Switch>
    {routes.map((route, idx) => {
        return(route.component && (
            <Route key={idx} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} name={route.name}
                render={(props) => (<route.component {...props} />)}
            />
        ));
    })}
    <Redirect from="/" to="/components" />
</Switch>
```

On my app, I have a navigation bar, which is built on the fly from a list of object specified in a variable. Here each nav-item specifies which data we want to access --

```js
var navDataList = [
    { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data A", to: "/components" },
    { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data B", to: "/components" },
    .
    .
    .
    { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data Z", to: "/components" },
]
```

and they are created with this --

```js
<CSidebarNav>
    <CCreateElement items={navDataList} components={{CSidebarNavItem}} />
</CSidebarNav>
```

So what I'm basically trying to do is to process `data_A`, `data_B` and `data_C` etc. using the same component `Component1` when a user clicks the nav link `Data A`, `Data B` and `Data C`, respectively.

What I understood is that I have specify which data object I want to process inside the `navList` as a props. But I couldn't figure out how to that.

How do I solve this problem?

The documentations on [CoreUI React](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-react) components are here: [`CSidebarNavItem`](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/sidebar.html), [`CSidebarNav`](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/sidebar.html), [`CCreateElement`](https://coreui.io/react/docs/components/CCreateElement/).

---

### A solution that somewhat works:

Inside the `navDataList`, if I specify these parameters, I can access from `Component1`:

```js
var navDataList = [
    { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data A", 
        to: { 
            pathname: "/components",
            hash: "data_A_will_be_default",
            params: { data: "data_A" },
        },
    }, 
    { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data B", 
        to: { 
            pathname: "/components",
            hash: "data_B",
            params: { data: "data_B" },
        },
    }, 
    ...
];
```

and then identifying within `Component1`:

```js
const Component1 = (props) => {
    var data = data_A; // default data to process
    if (props.location.params && props.location.params.data) {
        if (props.location.params.data === "data_B") {
            data = data_B;
        }
    }
    return(/* render component with data */);
}
```

But it's not responsive and there is a lag. The `params.data` doesn't update instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a single "components" route path that takes the data as a route parameter and accessed in the `Component1`.

Routes - define a path with route param `"/components/:data"`

```
routes = [
  { path: "/components/:data", name: "Component1", component: Component1, }
  // there are more components but they are not relevant here.
];
```

Links - link to a specific path with data specified

```
var navDataList = [
  { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data A", to: "/components/A" },
  { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data B", to: "/components/B" },
  .
  .
  .
  { _tag: "CSidebarNavItem", name: "Data Z", to: "/components/Z" },
];
```

Access [match](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match) params via [Route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) or [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) react hook

```
const Component1 = props => {
  const { data } = props.match.params;
  ...
}
```

or

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component1 = props => {
  const { data } = useParams();
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I have couple of questions: 1. Isn't it the case that `path:` in the `route` has to match with the directory structure? 2. Should I create a directory called `:data` in the `/components` path? 3. In the `navDataList`, in the case of `/components/A`, do I need to create a directory called `A` inside `/components` and keep the `data_A` there? I'm new to React.

Comment: @ramgorur For (1) and possibly (2) I'm not quite sure I follow this question about directory structure, the path is what is in the browser's address bar, so any underlying file/directory structure is irrelevant, it doesn't need to match anything in the router. In "/components/:data" `:data` is a placeholder for what is *actually* in the url. For (3) I just assumed keeping whatever/however you were importing `data_A`, `data_B`, etc.. the same in `Component1` and were using a map lookup or `switch` statement to grab the correct data object.